# Publishing a Read activity through facebook app failing for Auth Dialog Preview User

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

We are using the built-in 'Read' action for our facebook app, to publish the activity `'... read an article'` onto the user's timeline. The publish works fine for all the developers of the app.

However, when we try using the "Auth Dialog Preview User" for publishing, (which is used by Facebook to approve the usage of the action), the publish fails with the following OAuthException:

`{"Code" : 2, "message": "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later."}`

This is causing our submission of the action for approval to be rejected with: `"We are unable to test this action according to the usage instructions you provided."`

Any ideas on what could be causing the aforementioned error?

Here's how we are publishing the action:

```
FB.api(
        '/me/news.reads',
        'post',
        { article : uri },
        function(response) {
                       if (!response || response.error) {
                          console.log('Error occured while publishing as an article!');
                          console.log(response);
                       } else {
                          console.log('Post as an article was successful! Action ID: ' + response.id);
                       }
            });
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem trying to publish activities with the test user on my app as well.  Sandbox mode isn't enabled on my production app and it fails with the test user.  I either get "Some of the aliases you requested do not exist" or "An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Facebook app approval, not programming.

Answer (score 0):

In app settings disable Sandbox Mode.

Comment: We've checked, and the sandbox mode had throughout been disabled for our app. Sometimes, the action does get published, but most of the times, it gives the same OAuth exception